# How to align a Bootstrap form-select with previous row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 form with floating labels in input and select elements.[image: as show in this screenshot] The Track select lines up perfectly with the Location name input above it but the Product select is slightly too far to the left of the Track select.  It also has a slightly narrower width than the row above.

Here's the html for the fields.

```
<div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 mb-2">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <input id="clear-name" name="LocationName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="x" value="">
                                                <label class="text-muted">Location name</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-3 mb-2">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <select id="track-length" name="LocationTrackLength" class="form-select text-center" required>
                                                    <option></option>
                                                        <option value="7">7 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="9">9 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="10">10 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="11">11 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="13">13 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="15">15 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="21">21 ft</option>
                                                    <option value="custom-length">Custom&hellip;</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <label>Track</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <select id="ceiling-height" name="LocationCeilingHeight" class="form-select text-center" required>
                                                    <option></option>
                                                        <option value="8">8 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="8.5">8.5 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="9">9 ft</option>
                                                        <option value="9.5">9.5 ft</option>
                                                    <option value="custom-height">Custom&hellip;</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <label>Ceiling</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="row mb-2">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-floating">
                                                    <select id="location-product" name="LocationProducts.HospitalProductID" class="form-select text-center" required>
                                                            <option selected></option>
                                                         
                                                            <optgroup label="Textile">
                                                                    <option value="227" data-defaultprotocol="">96 x 36 Blue Stripe Textile</option>
                                                                    <option value="228" data-defaultprotocol="1182">96 x 36 Green stripes</option>
                                                            </optgroup>
                                                                                                                      
                                                            <optgroup label="Poly">
                                                                    <option value="223" data-defaultprotocol="1183">Transparence Snap on 96in x 72in</option>
                                                                    <option value="222" data-defaultprotocol="1182">Transparence Snap on 96in x 65in</option>
                                                                    <option value="224" data-defaultprotocol="1181">Yellow Stripes Poly  92 x 36 92in x 36in</option>
                                                            </optgroup>
                                                                                                                                                                              </select>
                                                    <label>Product</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

The Location name field and the Product field both have the same offset and column widths (col-sm-6 offset-sm-3) so I can't figure out why they are displayed differently and how to fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your structure in the last row is different compare to the other two above, remove the div with class `row` outside and move the class `mb-2` to the offset div like above and it will work fine

Comment: The structure for the last line is the same as for the row containing the Location name.  I need the div with class=row so the Product select is displayed on a separate row than the Track and Ceiling height above it.